# Web Service limits for inbound calls to managed package

Tags: webservices, governorlimits, rest

I am developing an AppExchange managed package intended for multiple organizations. I have a web-service in the managed application which I will invoke from my java based server to achieve few functionalities. I have read the governor limits and could not find any limits on inbound web-service limits calls and RESTful service call. I would like to know if there is any limits before I start my application.

Answer (score 2):

I seems that they count against your API limits described here: 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm

Go on reading here for more details:
[Understanding Rest Apex and Webservice Limit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16597/understanding-rest-apex-and-webservice-limit)