# RestContext requestBody size limit

Tags: apexrest, rest-service

According to what i found, HttpPost doesn't have size limit, but usually limited by the server to request is sent to (https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post).

Is there a size limit for RestContext requestBody (HttpPost) in salesforce?
I couldn't find any documentation on limitations regarding HttpPost in salesforce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK  it's 6 MB for synchronous Apex or 12 MB for asynchronous Apex.

More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)

Comment: Hi Bananka, Thanks for the reply. I've read the article you mentioned but i'm not sure that httprequest limit is the same as restrequest limit.
In these articles: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restcontext.htm
and
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_requestBody

they do not mention limitations. Do you think that they have the same limitations as httprequest?

Comment: Hi Dagish, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Anyway, I believe the limits are the same. Please check [this link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16597/understanding-rest-apex-and-webservice-limit) out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about size of request body you want to do a post to Rest Resource.. then it is 3 MB. I never get it to work more then 3 MB. I have tested with a traditional JavaScript http post.
There could be some work around I am thinking for my solution , one of which could be doing it in chunks by multiple post requests.